# D3 - Sorting Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

I've created a stacked bar chart following [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208).

However, I would like to sort the values from the largest to the smallest (so the rectangles in each column are in descending order by size), so the end result is something like this (pseudocode):

original values: Retailer 1, 3.94, 1.92, 7.14, 0.08, , 0.75, , 1.42, ,

sorted values: Retailer 1, 7.14, 3.94, 1.92, 1.42, 0.75, 0.08, , , ,

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253834/sorting-a-d3-js-stacked-bar-chart) with no luck and other searches for stacked bar sorting only sort the whole bar and not the values within the bar ([like this](http://bl.ocks.org/KatiRG/f7d064cd9c3efbc3c360)). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339828/sort-data-for-d3-stacked-bar-chart) is really close, but I haven't been able to properly tweak my dataset to get it working.

stack.order(d3.stackOrderDescending) alters the bars, but is not sorting everything by value properly. data.sort() doesn't appear to do the job either (as I'd be comparing one column to the next). I've also tried manually sorting the CSV, but because the "brands" are the keys, they end up outputting in alphabetical order.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you for your time.

Plunkr below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/kp1apRjCtNDo9G1FWlJF?p=preview

The code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};

var containerWidth = $('.graph__container').width(),
    containerHeight = $('.graph__container').height(),
    width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select(".graph__container")
            .append('svg');

svg.attr({
  'width' : width + margin.left + margin.right,
  'height': height + margin.top + margin.bottom
});

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .rangeRound([0, width])
          .padding(0.1)
          .align(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#8648CD", "#D66EC2", "#229ED8", "#2251C3"]);

var stack = d3.stack()
              .order(d3.stackOrderAscending)
              .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.retailer; }));
  z.domain(data.columns.slice(2));

  stacked = stack.keys(data.columns.slice(2))(data);

  var bars = g.selectAll(".bars")
              .data( stacked );

  bars.exit()
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .remove();

  var barEnter = bars.enter()
                     .append("g");

  bars = barEnter.merge(bars)
                 .attr("class", "bars")
                 .attr('data-brand', function(d) { return d.key; })
                 .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
                 .attr('stroke', 'white')
                 .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
                 .style('opacity', 1);

    var rect = bars.selectAll(".rect")
                   .data(function(d) { return d; });

    var rectEnter = rect.enter()
                        .append("rect");

    rect = rectEnter.merge(rect)
                    .attr('class', 'rect');
    rect.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .remove();

    rect.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.retailer); }) 
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
        .attr('data-etailer', function(d) { return d.data.retailer; })
        .attr("height", function(d) {return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
        .attr("width", (x.bandwidth() / 1.2))
        .style('opacity', 1);
});

function type(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 2, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i)
    t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
    d.total = t;
    return d;
}
```